# how do I run updateOrCreate on a relationship if id is null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got this code:

```
$model->relation->updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->id], $dataArray);
```

and I recieve the following error:

> Call to a member function updateOrCreate() on null

It seems I can't have `id` be `null` which can happen in my case, I may send null.

I expected `updateOrCreate()` to be able to handle this case. If `id` is `null` then create new record otherwise just update.

How can I update or create relationship that may not exist without this error getting in the way?

Comment: Actualy, it's `$model->relation` that is null. Can you show the code before that line?

Comment: Can you try `$model->relation()->updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->id], $dataArray);`. At the moment your trying to call `updateOrCreate()` on a nonexisting model / collection.

Comment: I used different approach on similar situation: `$ids[] = Image::updateOrCreate(...` and then sync it with the model `$model->relation()->sync($ids,true)`

Comment: You need to send incremented id in case of creating or just send `0` in place of  `$request->id` when creating new one

Answer (score 0):

Hey :) just execute the relationship to get the actual eloquent model as below

**Note:** instead of `$model->relation->` do `$model->relation()->`

```
$model->relation()->updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->id], $dataArray);
```